# How to pass in section value while storing indexPath in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, nsmutablearray, nsindexpath

I am trying to store indexPath in NSMutableArray

```
    [checkBoxIndexArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:?]];


   - (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths
    {

           cell.checkBox.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check"];

           [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:checkBoxIndexArray];

    }
```

but i don't know on what value shall i put for inSection. I tried entering 0,1 but still it's not working. I am getting following error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

i am getting this error for following code

```
[self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:checkBoxIndexArray];
```

Please tell me what value shall i put for inSection.

Comment: Did you try setting section as indexPath.section ?  Also, if you already have the indexPath you need to save, why don't you add the indexPath object you have directly to the array instead of creating a replica.

Comment: i tried setting indexPath.section but still i am getting the same error

Comment: From the error you are getting, it seems that you are inserting or deleting cell dynamically. Could you please explain in details when and where you are getting this error also show code for tableView dataSources.

Comment: Please put the whole code that you have try. Where you adding this `indexPath`object

Comment: Make sure the array count of checkBoxIndexArray and the array you are returning from numberOfItemAtIndexPath dataSource should be same. You are getting this error because the count is not same.

Answer (score 2):

you should use
`[checkBoxIndexArray addObject: indexPath];`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath=[Your_Table_Name indexPathForSelectedRow];
[checkBoxIndexArray addObject: indexPath];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
[checkBoxIndexArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:?]]
```

is same as doing this

```
[checkBoxIndexArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]]
```

OR Doing this

`[checkBoxIndexArray addObject:indexPath]`

Add the indexPath directly, and later on access the rows or section values as you please.

Comment: i tried both the solutions you gave but still i am getting the same error

Comment: when are you trying to store the indexpath?